# Proving that a specific function is discontinuous on a specific curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I need to investigate at which points the following function is continuous:[image]

It is clear that for any point with $y \neq  x^{2} $, it is continuous. I suspect that along the curve $y =x^{2} $ it is not continuous. For specific points, I used to prove discontinuity by sequential characterization, for instance: considering the sequence $(1, \frac{n}{n+1} )$ which converges to $(1,1)$, it is easy to show that f is not continuous at $(1,1)$. But how to generalize this argument?

Comment: Consider $y=x^2+\frac{1}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: It gave me an idea, but along the process of using that idea I noticed that f might be actually continuous only at $(0,0)$ among the points satisfying $y =x^{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @QC-QAOA 's idea, I wrote down a proof but as I am not sure any feedback is appreciated: $ \forall x \neq 0$ take the sequence $ (x, x^{2}+ \frac{1}{n}  )  \rightarrow (x, x^{2} )$. Then $
f( x_{n} , y_{n} ) =  y_{n} =  (x^{2}+ \frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow x^{2}  \neq 0 = f(x, x^{2} )$. By sequential characterization of continuity, f is discontinuous at all points $(x, x^{2} )$ with $x \neq 0$.

However, f is continuous at $(0,0)$: Take any sequence $( x_{n} , y_{n} ) \rightarrow (0,0)$. Then $(y_n) \rightarrow 0 $. Notice that $f( x_{n} , y_{n} )  \leq  | y_{n} | \rightarrow 0  $. So, $f( x_{n} , y_{n} )  \rightarrow 0  $

Comment: Looks good, the function is indeed discontinuous at all $y=x^2$ except $x=y=0$